# conversion of blob to pdf in java

Tags: java

i am not able to convert my blob data to its original pdf file.it saying file is damaged could nnot be read.
my code snippet as below:

```
w_ItemCode =w_rs.getString(1) ;
w_FileName = w_rs.getString(2);
Blob w_Blob = w_rs.getBlob(3);
w_TOdate = w_rs.getString(4);
w_File = new File(w_Directory +"/"+ w_ItemCode+"_"+ w_FileName);
if(!w_File.exists())
    w_File.createNewFile();
if(w_Blob != null && w_Blob.length() > 0) {
    InputStream w_BLOBStream = w_Blob.getBinaryStream();
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(w_BLOBStream);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to do ``PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(w_Blob.getBytes(1, w_Blob.length()));`` just to check?

Comment: Can you post the actual stacktrace please?